# Postgres regular expression to find procedures with wrong Update syntax

Tags: regex, postgresql

My Postgres database was migrated from MySQL using a tool and the code base has lot of syntax issues.

One of the issues is with the UPDATE statements inside procedures where the column name contains alias name as below.

```
UPDATE table1 t1 SET t1.col1 = 'some_value';
```

Having alias name after `SET` keyword as in `t1.col1` is a wrong syntax in Postgres.

As the number of procedures is huge, I'm trying to write a regular expression to find which procedures have this pattern.

```
select proname, prosrc from pg_proc 
where regexp_replace(prosrc, E'[\\n\\r]+', ' ', 'g' ) ~* '[:UPDATE:]([[:space:]]+)[:set:]([[:space:]]+)^[a-z]([a-z]|[0-9])+\.^[a-z]([a-z]|[0-9])+([[:space:]]*)[:=:]';
```

The `regexp_replace` part on the left side of the condition is to remove line breaks which works fine. The main part on the right side is not returning the desired result.

I am trying to find the procedures that has `UPDATE` keyword followed by one or more space, followed by SET keyword, followed by one more space, followed by one more alphanumeric characters (which starts with an alphabet), followed by a dot(.) , followed by one more alphanumeric characters (which starts with an alphabet), followed by zero or more spaces, followed by an equal to sign (=).

But the statement I formed seems to be wrong. Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: In the update you posted, the problem is the alias in the `SET` clause.  Really there could be so many problems thst a single regex may not find.  And even if the regex does find the problem, it still has to be corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below query gives me the expected results. It checks for code where we have `SET` followed by one or more space, followed by one or more alphanumeric character and `_`, followed by a dot(`.`), followed by one or more alphanumeric character and `_`, followed by one or more spaces and followed by `=`.
This fetches all the procedures that have the issue that I posted in question.

```
select proname, prosrc from pg_proc 
where regexp_replace(prosrc, E'[\\n\\r]+', ' ', 'g' ) 
~* '( SET)[[:space:]]+([a-z]|[0-9]|(_))+\.([a-z]|[0-9]|(_))+[[:space:]]+(=)';
```

Comment: If this works, then I stand corrected that it's too complex for a Regex...  Nicely done.

Answer (score 2):

I think this may be more complex than you think...  A procedure/function may have more than one update statement, and a simple regex will likely come up with many false positives.

I think you want a function to do a better job of eliminating false positives that result from:

- Alias that occurs after the update, in a separate statement (after the semicolon) -- fix by splitting statements by semicolons
- Aliases within the update that occur after a `FROM` or `WHERE` clause, which are valid and not syntax errors
- Less frequent, aliases used in a CTE prior to the update - fix by ignoring everything prior to the `update` keyword

Here is a boilerplate for what I think will get you close and minimize false positives:

```
create or replace function find_bad_syntax()
returns setof text
language plpgsql as
$BODY$
  DECLARE
    r pg_proc%rowtype;
    dml varchar[];
    eval varchar;
    alias varchar;
  BEGIN
    FOR r IN
      SELECT * FROM pg_proc WHERE prosrc ilike '%update%'
    LOOP
      dml := string_to_array (r.prosrc, ';');
      foreach eval in array dml
      loop
        alias := substring (lower (eval), 'update [\w.]+\s+(\w+)');
      
        continue when alias is null or lower (alias) = 'set';
      
        eval := regexp_replace (eval, 'from\s+.*', '', 'i');
        eval := regexp_replace (eval, 'where\s.*', '', 'i');
        eval := regexp_replace (eval, '^.*update', '', 'i');
        if eval ~* (alias || '\.\w+\s*=') then
     -- if eval ~* (alias || '\.\w+\s+=') then
          return next format ('PROC: %s ALIAS: %s => ERROR: %s', r.proname, alias, eval);
        end if;
      end loop;
    END LOOP;
  END;
$BODY$
```

So to get the results simply:

```
select * from find_bad_syntax()
```

I did a test run, and your function did show up in the results.

Comment: Tried this function, this has not shown some procedures that have alias in SET clause.

Comment: Yeah it’s a boilerplate…. Not comprehensive.  Can you give an example of a syntax it doesn’t pick up!

Comment: UPDATE tabl_name tbl
SET tbl.colum=some_value;
It didn't pick a code like this one.

Comment: Good observation, and silly me...  I assumed there would be spaces between the field and the = sign, but that's optional in DML.  I fixed it and commented out the wrong line; difference between a + and *.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in PostgreSQL this is not working:

```
UPDATE table1 t1 SET t1.col1 = 'some_value';
```

But, this is working correctly:

```
UPDATE table1 t1 SET col1 = 'some_value';
```

So we only need to clear the update field alias.
Example for do it:

```
with t1(txt) as (
    select 'UPDATE table1 t1 SET t1.col1 = some_value'
)
select regexp_replace(t1.txt, 'SET (.*)\d\.', 'SET ', 'g') from t1
```

Comment: This is for removing the alias. My ask is to find all the procedures that have this extra alias name in the SET clause from pg_proc table.

Answer (score -1):

For finding, selecting:

```
with t1(txt) as (
    select 'UPDATE table1 t1 SET t1.col1 = some_value'
)
select * from t1 where t1.txt ~ 'SET (.*)\d\.'
```

Comment: This is EXTREMELY over-simplified to the specific example in the question.  For example, the syntax on this is fine, but it will still yield from your query: `UPDATE table1 t1 SET col1 = some_value; select t2.* from table t2` and it will fail for this: `UPDATE table1 t SET t.col1 = some_value`.  The OP wants to find any function that might have an issue.

Answer (score -1):

Some small changes:

```
with t1(txt) as (
    select 'UPDATE table1 t1 SET t1.col1 = some_value'
    union all 
    select 'UPDATE table1 tbp3232 SET tbp3232.col1 = some_value'
    union all 
    select 'select pp3.* from table1 pp3'
    union all 
    select 'UPDATE table1 SET col1 = some_value'
    union all 
    select 'UPDATE table1 t SET t.col1 = some_value'
)
select * from t1 where t1.txt ~ 'SET (.*)\w\.'


--Result: 
'UPDATE table1 t1 SET t1.col1 = some_value'
'UPDATE table1 tbp3232 SET tbp3232.col1 = some_value'
'UPDATE table1 t SET t.col1 = some_value'
```

Comment: For single SQL statements this is better, but the OP is looking for updates in procedures/functions that have potential syntax errors.  Run this logic right now in your database:  `select proname, prosrc from pg_proc where prosrc ~ 'SET (.*)\w\.'` and I think you'll see why this is incomplete.  Also it ignores update statements where `set` is not uppercase (easily resolved, but I had to point it out).  Bottom line -- I think this is too complicated for a regex alone.  Some tasks are just too big for a single regex.